# How to keep a menuflyout open after clicking on togglemenuflyout item?

Tags: c#

I have found no examples that contain a property to manipulate a menuflyout so it stays open if user clicks on togglemenuitem but will still close if focus is lost or esc button is clicked.

The functionality I would prefer is that it stay open so user can click up to 24 toggleMenuFlyoutItems if preferred without having to click on the menuflyout button every time.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: No, I have not. I can use the MenuFlyout.showAt(Btn) and the Menu will be opened when I connect it to a different button entirely. I've tried using the closed method that is called on MenuFlyout but when I use MenuFlyout.showAt(Btn) and it's connected to the preferred button it seems to still be overrode by another method built into MenuFlyout that closes it after I call the method to keep it open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by switching away from a MenuFlyout element.  Instead, use an AppBar and a Flyout instead of a MenuFlyout.  Here is the appropriate XAML code from MainPage.xaml

```
<AppBar Grid.Row="3" Background="LightGray">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <AppBarButton Label="Filter">
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Filter"/>
            </AppBarButton.Icon>
            <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                <Flyout>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="IncludeCompletedCheckbox" IsChecked="True" Click="FilterCompletedTasks_Clicked">Completed</CheckBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Flyout>
            </AppBarButton.Flyout>
        </AppBarButton>
        <AppBarButton Label="Sort">
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Sort"/>
            </AppBarButton.Icon>
            <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                <Flyout>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <RadioButton x:Name="SortMethod_Unsorted" GroupName="SortOptions" IsChecked="True" Click="SortTasks_Clicked">Unsorted</RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="SortMethod_ByTitle" GroupName="SortOptions" Click="SortTasks_Clicked">By Title</RadioButton>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Flyout>
            </AppBarButton.Flyout>
        </AppBarButton>
    </StackPanel>
</AppBar>
```

Comment: Adrian, thanks for your reply. I also figured out that you can use listview, gridview, listbox in the flyout as well. That also fixed the problem. I hope this helps anyone in the future.

Comment: Link is now dead, best to remove it please.

Comment: Thanksd @peterincumbria - I've removed the link.  The XAML is still valid.

Answer (score 10):

I know this thread is old but I found something that may help. FlyoutBaseClosingEventArgs has a Cancel property starting Win10, v1607; (per UWP API Doc). You could catch the MenuFlyout Closing event and set Cancel to true if you want to keep the MenuFlyout open.

```
<MenuFlyout x:Name="MyFlyout" 
            Closing="MyFlyout_Closing" 
            Closed="MyFlyout_Closed" 
    <MenuFlyoutItem />            
    <MenuFlyoutItem />
</MenuFlyout>

private void MyFlyout_Closing(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.FlyoutBase sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.FlyoutBaseClosingEventArgs args)
{
    // Whatever logic you need to decide
    args.Cancel = true; 
}
```

This may be less than ideal because it seems you would need to setup another property outside the MenuFlyout to use as a trigger to let it close. There may be a way to use the Tag properties on the items as well. I hope his is useful. Lastly, this is my first post here, sorry for any improper post etiquette.